# move xml tag to another place in xml and id generation using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

Input `XML`:

```
&lt;author-group&gt;
&lt;author&gt;    
&lt;given-name&gt;aaa&lt;/given-name&gt;    
&lt;surname&gt;bbb&lt;/surname&gt;    
&lt;orfid&gt;a&lt;/orfid&gt;    
&lt;e-address type="email"&gt;abc@gmail.com&lt;/e-address&gt;    
&lt;/author&gt;    
&lt;affiliation&gt;chennai&lt;/affiliation&gt;    
&lt;/author-group&gt;
```

Output `XML` should be:

```
&lt;contrib-group content-type="all"&gt;    
&lt;contrib contrib-type="author"&gt;    
&lt;name&gt;    
&lt;given-name&gt;aaa&lt;/given-name&gt;   
&lt;surname&gt;bbb&lt;/surname&gt;   
&lt;/name&gt;   
&lt;xref ref-type="aff" rid="af1"/&gt;  
&lt;xref ref-type="email" rid="em1"/&gt;   
&lt;/contrib&gt;  
&lt;aff id="af1"&gt;chennai&lt;/aff&gt;  
&lt;ext-link id="em1"&gt;abc@gmail.com&lt;/ext-link&gt;
&lt;/contrib-group&gt;
```

Can anyone help me to convert the input `XML` to output `XML` using XSLT?

Comment: Why are you showing us escaped markup? Neither one of these is XML.

Answer (score 0):

Hello and welcome to Stackoverflow.

Assuming that your escaped markup is just a mistake, the following XSL will produce the exact output you asked.

However,there is no "generation" in it, as I have no idea what you meant by this. Please ask a clearer question if needed.

## XML input

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<author-group>
<author>
<given-name>aaa</given-name>
<surname>bbb</surname>
<orfid>a</orfid>
<e-address type="email">abc@gmail.com</e-address>
</author>
<affiliation>chennai</affiliation>
</author-group>
```

## XSL stylesheet

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
>
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="author-group">
    <xsl:element name="contrib-group">
      <xsl:attribute name="content-type">
        <xsl:value-of select="'all'"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:element name="contrib">
        <xsl:attribute name="contrib-type">
          <xsl:value-of select="'author'"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:element name="name">
          <xsl:copy-of select="./author/given-name"/>
          <xsl:copy-of select="./author/surname"/>
        </xsl:element>
        <xsl:element name="xref">
          <xsl:attribute name="ref-type">
            <xsl:value-of select="'aff'"/>
          </xsl:attribute>
          <xsl:attribute name="rid">
            <xsl:value-of select="'af1'"/>
          </xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:element>
        <xsl:element name="xref">
          <xsl:attribute name="ref-type">
            <xsl:value-of select="'email'"/>
          </xsl:attribute>
          <xsl:attribute name="rid">
            <xsl:value-of select="'em1'"/>
          </xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:element>
      </xsl:element
      <xsl:element name="aff">
        <xsl:attribute name="id">
          <xsl:value-of select="'af1'"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:value-of select="./affiliation"/>
      </xsl:element>
      <xsl:element name="ext-link">
        <xsl:attribute name="id">
          <xsl:value-of select="'em1'"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:value-of select="./author/e-address"/>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

## XML output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<contrib-group content-type="all">
  <contrib contrib-type="author">
    <name>
      <given-name>aaa</given-name>
      <surname>bbb</surname>
    </name>
    <xref ref-type="aff" rid="af1" />
    <xref ref-type="email" rid="em1" />
  </contrib>
  <aff id="af1">chennai</aff>
  <ext-link id="em1">abc@gmail.com</ext-link>
</contrib-group>
```